# Correct link_to route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure what I am missing. First off this is a valid route if I manually navigate to it...

```
/orientations/1/registrations
```

This shows me all registrations associated with the first orientaiton. Now I am trying to create a link_to to these routes in my view. Here is the output of rake routes...

http://pastie.org/pastes/8440065/text

In my view I am trying to do...

```
 <%= link_to "R", orientation_registration_path(orientation) %></li>
```

...and the error I am getting is...

```
No route matches 
{
  :action         =>  "show", 
  :controller     =>  "registrations", 
  :orientation_id =>  #<Orientation 
    id: 1, 
    class_date: "2013-10-17",  
    class_time: "11:30am", 
    seats: 30, 
    active: true, 
    created_at: "2013-10-28 14:22:42", 
    updated_at: "2013-10-28 14:22:42">
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `s` my friend

```
 <%= link_to "R", orientation_registrations_path %></li>
```

Comment: you're missing a route parameter too!

Answer (score 1):

Check the name of your routes carefully!

In this case the route that matches the URL you want is:

```
orientation_registrations GET    /orientations/:orientation_id/registrations(.:format)          registrations#index
```

Note `registrations`, not `registration`!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your rake routes output, the path you need to use is

```
orientation_registrations_path(orientation)
```

That will generate the correct link. From rake routes output:

```
orientation_registrations GET    /orientations/:orientation_id/registrations(.:format)          registrations#index
```